# Description environment redefined

Tags: templates, description

I use the Latex templates from [Springer](http://www.google.com/url?q=ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/mathegl/mono/refguide.pdf&sa=U&ei=NM0iUKKtBITasgaB9oG4Bw&ved=0CBEQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNEaPQv_oVwPJ_Bi9_IiHN76EaVsIQ) for a project, and to my surprise, the description environment doesn't work correctly - the item labels are not bold.

I don't know where this is customized in the templates, but would like the old (standard) behaviour. How can I redefine the redefined description environment to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may copy the environment's definition from `book`/`report`/`article` into your preamble. (I use `\let\descriptionlabel\relax` in case your custom class doesn't feature this command.)

```
\makeatletter
% Instead of \newenvironment
\renewenvironment{description}
               {\list{}{\labelwidth\z@ \itemindent-\leftmargin
                        \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel}}
               {\endlist}
% Instead of \newcommand*
\let\descriptionlabel\relax
\newcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep
                                \normalfont\bfseries #1}
\makeatother
```

I'm not sure which version of `svmono` you're using, but as an alternative it *might* work to add the following to your preamble (and hereby keep the other enhancements to the environment):

```
\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep\normalfont\bfseries #1\hfil}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your second (one-line) proposal does make the labels bold, but the indentation and the (exaggerated) distance between label and text make the description blocks still look weird. Your first proposal fixes that too and solves my problem perfectly - thanks again.